# Clairaut's form of $(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)(y\frac{dy}{dx}+x)=a^2\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question is to find the Clairaut's form of differential equation 
$$(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)(y\frac{dy}{dx}+x)=a^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$ I know clairaut's equation is of the form $y=x\frac{dy}{dx}+f(\frac{dy}{dx})$ but i was not able to reduce given equation to this form.

Any Hint would be Sufficient !

Comment: You can expand the brackets to give a quadratic in $y$ and then solve this via the quadratic formula. This gives an equation of the form $y = x y' + f(x,y')$. Although, this isn't quite in the suggested from as $f$ also depends on $x$.

Comment: So can we call it a clairaut's equation because as per definition, $f$ should depend only on $y'$

Comment: Perhaps not, although I'm unfamiliar with Clairaunt's equation. Perhaps this represents a commonly known generalised form of it. Alternatively there could be another way to rearrange your ODE (although I certainly couldn't see it).

Comment: May I ask where you found this problem? Is it an exercise of some book? Home work? ...

Comment: In India, there is one exam called UPSC. So I was solving previous year's maths questions papers and I found out this problem. And also, they also asked the general solution of this equation. You can see the problem by yourself. On page number 14, Q 6(a)   Check this link       http://www.civilserviceindia.com/upsc_questions/MATHS_I-mains-11.pdf

Comment: This seem to be a duplicate of [this old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491643/97236). I could not vote for duplication though, since that question does not have an upvoted/accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know no other way than trial and error.

The factor
$$
xy'(x)-y
$$
suggests the substitution
$$
u(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}
$$
but that leads to a dead end (try it out!).

The factor
$$
y(x)y'(x)+x
$$
suggests the substitution
$$
u(x)=y(x)^2+x^2.
$$
This leads to
$$
u(x)=-\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{a^2x}{2u'(x)}+\frac{x}{2}u'(x),
$$
which is *not* in the Clairaut form either! But this looks better! We find that it we let $t=x^2$ and $v(t)=u(x)$, then
$$
v(t)=-\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{a^2}{4v'(t)}+tv'(t),
$$
and *this* is in the Clairaut form. I leave it to you to solve the differential equation and substitute back again.

Comment: could you please explain the step in which you wrote $u(x)$ in terms of $u'(x)$ ???

Comment: Differentiate to get $u'=2yy'+2x$, solve for $y'$, insert into the original equation, and simplify.

Comment: So $y'=\frac{u'-2x}{2y}$, then where did $u(x)$ came from into the equation. Equation should only consists of $u'(x)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you do the calculation, you will see that you have an occurence of $x^2+y^2$ which will give you a $u$.

Comment: Yes i got it. Actually i was making a mistake in calculation. Thank you very much for the solution.